# Date/month validation

Tags: java, date

here is a description on what I'm trying to do:

> First, the program will print "Enter month>," and then the user must
>   enter a number. If the entered number is not in the range of 1 to 12
>   as the following error message is printed "Improper month.", And the
>   program then ends. If the entered month is correct, the program will
>   print "Enter the day of month>," and then the user must enter a
>   to-speech. If the number does not correspond to a day in the previous
>   input the month, the following error message is printed "Wrong day of
>   the month.", And the program then ends. If both the input month number
>   and the entered day of the month is correct, then the program should
>   print "The correct date.", And then terminated.

But I get this error below and I can't figure out why

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\ ][decimal separator=\,][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at upp.main(upp.java:10)
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class upp {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] numberOfDaysEachMonth = new int[]{31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    System.out.println("Enter month > ");
    Scanner month = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userInputMonth = Integer.parseInt(month.toString());
    if (userInputMonth > 0 && userInputMonth < 13) {
        System.out.println("Enter the day of month > ");
        Scanner day = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInputDay = Integer.parseInt(day.toString());
        if (userInputDay > 0 && userInputDay < numberOfDaysEachMonth[userInputMonth - 1]) {
            System.out.println("Correct date.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong date.");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong month.");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 int userInputMonth = Integer.parseInt(month.toString());
```

It should be either of below statement:

```
// Read as string, convert to int.
int userInputMonth = Integer.parseInt(month.next());

// Read as int using nextInt()
int userInputMonth = month.nextInt();
```

---

```
Scanner day = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Once you create an object of `Scanner`, you need not to create it again. Use the same object to read the further input from the `System.in`. It should be either of the below statement.

```
// Read as string, convert to int.
int userInputDay = Integer.parseInt(month.next());

// Read as int using nextInt()    
int userInputDay = month.nextInt();
```

---

You also need to use `<=` condition in the day check instead of `<`.

```
if (userInputDay > 0 && userInputDay <= numberOfDaysEachMonth[userInputMonth - 1])
```

**PS :** Rename the `Scanner` the object like `scanner` or `read` then use it for reading both **month** and **day**.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class upp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] numberOfDaysEachMonth = new int[]{31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    System.out.println("Enter month > ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userInputMonth = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
    if (userInputMonth > 0 && userInputMonth < 13) {
      System.out.println("Enter the day of month > ");

      int userInputDay = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
      if (userInputDay > 0 && userInputDay <= numberOfDaysEachMonth[userInputMonth - 1]) {
        System.out.println("Correct date.");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong date.");
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("Wrong month.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did change to Integer.parseInt(month.next()); and Integer.parseInt(month.next());.......But when I'm running the program it says that the day/month is correct regardless what i type

Comment: Add the System.out.println() for both and try.

Comment: Did you update both the places. Then it is working fine. `Scanner day = new Scanner(System.in);` This is not required, use the same `month` object reading the `day` value as well.

Comment: Maybe the coding is wrong, cause i want it to if i type the wrong day/month it should say wrong date/month but now it just says that its correct regardless what i type

Comment: @PejmanTehrani Your code is correct. You need to make two changes, where you are taking the input from the user. Also you need to remove your second scanner statement.

Comment: can you please copy the coding and do the correction? i can't get it work

Comment: @PejmanTehrani Also let me know, for what input it is failing, if it fails.

Comment: Still the same thing, it says that its correct regardless what i type

Comment: @PejmanTehrani Check here [Code output](http://ideone.com/vnItVM). input `month:1` and `day:31`, output: `correct date`.

Comment: @PejmanTehrani you should give input in the space separated format like `month day` or line separated `month` then `day` in the next line. Not the comma separated.

Comment: @PejmanTehrani with input like `1,2,3,4`, you should be getting, NumberFormatException.

Comment: I tried line separated but it still says correct regardless what number i type

Comment: @PejmanTehrani what is the code are you running, paste here in comment.

Comment: Enter month > 
1
Enter the day of month > 
2
Correct date.

Comment: Thanks a lot abhishek, you made my weekend

Answer (score 1):

```
int userInputMonth = Integer.parseInt(month.toString());
```

doesnt make any sense because month is a Scanner object and you converting its string representation to int which would always give you that exception instead you have to do only

```
int userInputMonth =  month.nextInt();
```

print the value of moth to check if its a valid integer or not.

You have same issue with `day` variable and also you can reuse `month` scanner instead. Full Code

```
try {
    int[] numberOfDaysEachMonth = new int[] {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    System.out.println("Enter month > ");
    Scanner month = new Scanner(System. in );
    int userInputMonth = month.nextInt();
    if (userInputMonth > 0 && userInputMonth < 13) {
        System.out.println("Enter the day of month > ");
        int userInputDay = month.nextInt();
        if (userInputDay > 0 && userInputDay < numberOfDaysEachMonth[userInputMonth - 1]) {
            System.out.println("Correct date.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong date.");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong month.");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/UFJNeh)